# Should the name of the proposal be in the subject of Area 51 Discussion Zone?

Tags: discussion, tags, area-51

What's the better pattern to identify proposals on Area 51 Discussion Zone?

Looking at question list it's hard to identify proposal related without tags or title.

1. the name of proposal in title of the question
2. tag with the name of the proposal
3. both
4. none
5. another, explain

Personally I prefer number 2

Comment: Shouldn't that be asked on the area 51 discussion zone..?

Comment: @Kop meta.stackoverflow.com is still the place for questions about Area 51, the website. The Discussion Zone is for talking about the actual proposals ...or perhaps we need meta.discussion.area51.stackexchange.com...